Lifting object with momentum generated by jerk of a piston
I want have some weight above a piston cylinder mechanism which I want to lift, using momentum generated by creating vacuum in cylinder and then releasing piston back which will create a momentum, so how to determine the size of cylinder to generate enough momentum, and mostly I will use a stopper which will stop the piston midway when released to transfer the momentum.

Think you need to draw a diagram for this, as this is confusing at the moment.

And you need to provide some numbers.
